# Space Complexity of Skip List is Wrong?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity, skip-lists

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list says that worst space complexity of skip list is O(n log(n)) but I don't agree at all.

Here is my proof:

Each time a skip list has at maximum log(n) layers, so each new node can be inserted at most log(n) times. If we start from a skip list with 1 node then this is how the total number of nodes grows:

[image]

In other words, the total sum after $n$ insertions is:

[image]

Which is much greater than O(n log(n))... (I just proved that S(n)=w(n^2) which is a contradiction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your confusion is summing twice.

First, you say the **total** number of nodes (and not new nodes) is `1->2->3->5->8->...` - and then you sum these numbers.

But, the total number of nodes for `n` elements is the element in the series with index `n`, not the summation of all elements up to `n`.

Comment: You are right thanks, two last notes 1) Why everyone says max number of layers is log(n) where is this mentioned or required why I can't insert same element infinity times? 2) Someone proved here that it could be omega(n log(n)) claiming each element appears exactly log(n) times but that's incorrect. when you add element you can add it max log(n) times given the current n not the last n. so it's n(log(something)) where this something grows from 1 to n...

Comment: (1) It depends on the implementation, but you can define a limit to the max levels one can add. (2) If analyzing worst case, this is Theta(nlogn), because in this analysis you **do** add each element log(n) times. (In fact, in average case analysis, this is going to be O(n), similar to trees, unsurprisingly)